# Why did my solution pass only 9/10 tests in Codesignal?

Tags: typescript

I am beginning to learn Typescript on Codesignal platform.
I came across [this exercise](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/bq2XnSr5kbHqpHGJC)

Here is the question for those who cannot access the link:

> Ratiorg got statues of different sizes as a present from CodeMaster
> for his birthday, each statue having an non-negative integer size.
> Since he likes to make things perfect, he wants to arrange them from
> smallest to largest so that each statue will be bigger than the
> previous one exactly by 1. He may need some additional statues to be
> able to accomplish that. Help him figure out the minimum number of
> additional statues needed.

> Example

> For statues = [6, 2, 3, 8], the output should be
> `makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) = 3`.
> Ratiorg needs statues of sizes 4, 5 and 7.

My solution was this

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues: number[]): number   {
let sorted: number[] = statues.sort();
let full = [];
for (let i = sorted[0]; i <= sorted[sorted.length-1]; i++)    {
    full.push(i);
}
var diff = full.filter(myCallBack);


function myCallBack(el) {
    return sorted.indexOf(el) < 0;
}

return diff.length;
```

When I ran the tests, only 9/10 of them were passed. The one I failed was a hidden test.

Also, when I try not to use the filter() method and instead calculate the difference between the sorted and full array by:

```
return full.length - sorted.length;
```

I got only 8/10.

Could anyone give me the reason(s)?

Comment: A guess: `statues.sort();` should be `statues.sort((a, b) => a - b);` [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007)

Comment: That's a quite complicated way. Get the smallest, get the biggest and then return `(biggest - smallest) - <number of actual statues> + 1`.

Comment: @Andreas assuming each number is unique.

Comment: Just FWIW: Assuming (because these descriptions are always inadequate) that they never give you the same size twice, you don't need to sort the array, and you don't need to filter anything. Make a single pass through the array to find the `min` and `max` values, and then it's literally `(max - min) + 1 - statues.length` .

Comment: @VLAZ There's nothing in the description that would indicate problems like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: In fact, I have read the solutions and many others did just that, which is a beautiful answer. However I still want to figure out why my naive approach did not work.

Comment: @ElNiño - They're probably marking it down for complexity.

Comment: @VLAZ: Indeed, it was stated in the question that these statues are of DIFFERENT sizes. So the numbers must be unique.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not sure if I'm getting what you said, but this is not a problem of complexity. There were 10 tests designed by the website to check if my solution covered all the possbile cases. As I said in the question, mine passed only 9 out of 10.

Comment: @ElNiño - I can't speak for that specific website, but some of them absolutely do test for complexity and mark down solutions that are over-complex. Or it's what VLAZ pointed out half an hour ago (your `sort` is incorrect). That seems the more likely reason.

Comment: @VLAZ : I just adjusted my code following your suggestion. Worked like a charm! Thank you all for your time and effort!